# testing by new paypal sandbox account

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, joomla-extensions

Is there any big change in paypal test sandbox account? i was testing using sandbox account before well but these days it seems i can't login to sandbox account using my previous login credentials! by going this link -

> https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-run

I read by searching through google.com that its needed to have a real paypal account to login to sandbox account! but i am in bangladesh where paypal is not available.So in this case am i wrong what i knew till now? or give me suggestions how to test using paypal sandbox test accounts properly when my country is not listed in paypal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have a live PayPal account to use the Sandbox. You do need to have an account on Developer.PayPal.com though. You need to be logged into Developer.PayPal.com to properly use the Sandbox.

When the new Developer.PayPal.com site was introduced it was required that users needed to have a PayPal account but that was ended.

Comment: please provide signup link in developer.paypal.com.as much i remember country bangladesh was a restriction when try to signup.waiting for replies

Comment: Ok i went to developer.paypal.com and signed up but i had to enter US info (it seems it not available globally yet).anyway going to applications->sandbox accounts i see accounts created which i used to test a paypal test payment from joomla site and it seems working.Is this Right way going?? i really use another country's paypal account to sell digital product sometimes.

Comment: You don't need a US address. It does ask for a business address but there isn't an option for country. You can create a Developer.PayPal.com account without a US address.